# How to prevent div refresh with jquery when a bootstrap modal is already open?

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog

I am refreshing a div every 30 seconds, inside the div I refresh there is a bootstrap modal box. If that modal is clicked and is open, then, when the div refreshes modal disappears leaving the whole page unclickable. I am trying to find a solution to this.

I am hoping to prevent div refreshing when modal box is open. Any ideas?
Thanks

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="alertModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="alertModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header bg-info text-white">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="alertModalLabel">Modal Title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        some content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#mainc').fadeOut('slow').load('index.php #mainc').fadeIn('slow');
  }, 30000);
});
```

Comment: Stop the interval when the modal opens, and restart it when it closes. *However* it's worth noting that making an AJAX request in an interval, even a lengthy one as in this example, can lead to server performance issues. I'd look at alternative methods of doing whatever you need to with this repeated `load()` call.

Comment: "Stop the interval when the modal opens, and restart it when it closes". good point, but how?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval

Comment: how do I know the modal is open? Can you please provide a whole answer? thank you

Comment: `shown.bs.modal` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution to this problem :

```
function setLoad() {$('#mainc').fadeOut('slow').load('index.php #mainc').fadeIn('slow');}
setInterval(setLoad,'10000');
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal','.modal',function(){setInterval(setLoad,'10000');});
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal','.modal',function(){for(var i=1;i<10000;i++){clearInterval(i);}});
```

Since hidden.bs.modal runs setInterval() with random ids, it was not possible to use clearInterval() without knowing the id.
Also be sure to put the js code above the ".modal" div, this worked better.